# Stop page scrolling from focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, focus

I just installed a script to focus at my first input field, which is toward the footer.  The focus works great, but the page scrolls to the bottom after loading.

Can I still use the focus and stop the page from scrolling down to the first input field?

http://www.ubspack.com/

Comment: try putting window.scroll(0,0) in document onload function after the line that puts input into focus.

Comment: Try my solution. This should be the best:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/31472878/931908

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
$(function(){
     $("input").focus();
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow'); 
});)
```

Comment: Try my solution. This should be the best:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/31472878/931908

Answer (score 2):

Insert this at the end of the page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.scrollTo(0, 0);
 </script>
```

This will again scroll the page to the top.

Comment: this code can be put in $(document).ready() or in $(function(){ })