# Nivo Lightbox - scrolling issue while in mobile view

Tags: android, jquery, css, mobile, nivo-slider

I'm struggling with Nivo Lightbox on my personal portfolio site. Unfortunately I can't make it  act correctly on mobile browsers, some scrolling problems occurs.

Please check on android browser, mobile chrome etc. http://www.krzysztofbalana.pl and try to open random project. On mobile you'll see that while trying to scroll down foreground content background is being scrolled instead of project description.

Thanks in advance!
Christopher

Comment: I'm also facing same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these links should help you. you need to focus on new element for scrolling:

[Disable scrolling when changing focus form elements ipad web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740253/disable-scrolling-when-changing-focus-form-elements-ipad-web-app)

[Javascript set focus to HTML form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500704/javascript-set-focus-to-html-form-element)