# Custom scrolling on iOS (and all mobile devices) when input is focused

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

**The problem:**

When the input is selected I want the screen to scroll so that the focused input is right at the top of the screen.

I want this to work on iOS and all other mobile devices.

---

### **This is what happens currently on iOS:**

[image]

---

### **This is what I want to happen... Notice where the page scrolls to:**

[image]

---

### **The code I'm currently trying out is:**

```
$('#input').on('focus focusin', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#anchor').offset().top
    }, 300);
})
```

This code works great on desktop, but as soon as I load the page up on my iPhone, it stops working completely and the default scroll behaviour takes over—as seen in the first gif.

Comment: Can you try with `body` instead of `html`? Like this `$('body').animate({...`

Comment: @JohnR tried that, doesn't work at all when `body` is used instead of `html`

Comment: You may try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9298941/1736186 of course change 0 to `offset().top`. In the second answer I can see that `e.preventDefault()` doesn't work since IOS 8. Also there is one more hack that I have in mind but it's kind of ugly. Use `setTimeout()` with about 300ms(?) delay to check if `window.scrollTop()` is equal to what You want. Otherwise repeat scroll animation. And check this ONLY if this is touch device: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819886/1736186

Comment: the problem is trying to change the default scroll behaviour

Comment: Can you try using position instead of offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the problem finally!

After hours and hours of mucking around, I figured out that the problem wasn't the code. The code shown in my question worked perfectly.

**The problem happened to be my local testing environment** (`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` in command prompt).

I still haven't pinpointed the reason. I have however determined that I'm using Django 1.11.4 and jQuery 3.1.1 on *both production and local testing environments*. So why this problem would occur is beyond me.

---

My best guess is that there is some incompatibility between jQuery and Django's local testing server.

Answer (score 4):

So you just need it to scroll so the top of the input becomes the top of the screen?

I have added 2 pixels gap above the input so that you can see the border at the top of the input still.

```
$('#input').on('focus', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top-2;
    }, 1000);
})
```