# focusout not triggered if focusin is set programatically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect a focus out event after focusin was set programatically. Take a look at the example: (click on blue element sets `focusin`, clicking on document should trigger `focusout`)

https://jsfiddle.net/k946vcza/1/

For some reason, if `focusin` is set with

```
  var focusin = new Event("focusin");
  red.dispatchEvent(focusin);
```

`focusout` does not get triggered  when clicked on the document. If you first click on the `red element` and then on document, then focusout is detected as expected.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

`focusin` won't trigger the focus event (demonstrated in that the element doesn't get highlighted), and since `focusout` requires the element to be focused, you won't see it get called.

If you do something like `setTimeout(()=>red.focus(), 0)` instead of `red.dispatchEvent(focusin)`, you will see the expected behaviour

Comment: thanks man! this seems to work. I've got a small subquestion. Every time I set focus with focus() function, browser scrolling seems to jump up to the element who gained focus. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/k946vcza/2/ . Is it possible to cancel this behaviour? It happens even when the "about to be focused" element is visible in viewport.

Comment: Maybe this question helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740253/disable-scrolling-when-changing-focus-form-elements-ipad-web-app