# Phonegap iOS - prevent scrolling on input focus

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am creating an iPad app using Phonegap. The app has a fixed landscape orientation and a menu running along the top, with a text box inside it on the top right. The app is a fixed (full screen) size and does not require scrolling.

When the user touches the text box that appears top right on iOS 6, the whole app slides left in order to place the text box in the centre of the screen, pushing the whole app left and leaving a blank space on the right.

How do I prevent this behaviour?

I currently have UIWebViewBounce set to NO and the following code in place to catch touchstart events:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

I also have this on the text box itself, which seems to work on iOS 5 (albeit with a stutter) but not on iOS 6:

```
$('#searchText').on("focus", function(event) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: 2023 solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76731361/480608. However, it may need to be adjusted to find the horizontal center rather than the vertical center since your app is in fixed landscape mode.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this javascript in an `onfocus` attribute in the `input` that you don't want to shift when being focused:

```
<input onfocus="this.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(0px,-10000px,0)'; webkitRequestAnimationFrame(function() { this.style.webkitTransform = ''; }.bind(this))"/>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I've had this friggin problem for iOS HTML app development, for about over 2 years!!! I've tried everything from JQUERY to iScroll to other javascript library crapolies. Thank you so much, an answer to my long life quest for an answer. Will accept once I'm able to.

Comment: YOU ARE WELCOME XD LOL

Comment: After updating Cordova & Phongap to latest versions, it appears that your fix no longer works... lmao

Comment: Just kidding. I'll find something

Comment: Aight still waiting on ya buddy

Comment: You still waiting for an answer?

Comment: this work to get from an input the other but it doesn't work when I try to use backspace and go back to the previous input, here it makes my screen jump

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the following css styles to your body elemnt:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none; 
-webkit-user-select: none; 
-khtml-user-select: none; 
-moz-user-select: none; 
-ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

It prevents user selection on links and other stuff. Maybe it will be helfull for you.

Comment: This doesn't work for me I'm afraid kreig - sorry, but thanks all the same.