# Prevent iPhone web-app from scrolling on focus of an input field

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications, webkit, scroll

When you click on an input field on a website in the iPhone Safari it automatically scrolls the content the way the input will be centered. I would like to prevent Safari of doing that and found several solutions, one of them: [Preventing an <input> element from scrolling the screen on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952782/preventing-an-input-element-from-scrolling-the-screen-on-iphone/7949391#7949391) where after focusing we use jQuery.animate() to move back where we were.

Unfortunately this only works as long as I call the website through Safari. As soon as I add the website to the homescreen, the automatic scrolling on a focus appears again.
Now when I write the position of the body/html-element before and after correcting it (with the methode mentioned above) into the console everything seems as if it works correctly: The web-app think it has scrolled back to the place it should even if I haven't noticed anything visually.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the auto-centering on input click for me in React (JSX) with:

`<input onMouseDown={ev => ev.preventDefault()} />`

It should work with any way of attaching an event handler, e.g. **addEventListener**

Comment: This doesn't work for me. By calling preventDefault(), it stops the text input field from getting focused at all, so it's unusable: https://jsfiddle.net/karlovac/ty2qdLk9/34/ . (URL for testing on an iPhone directly: https://fiddle.jshell.net/karlovac/ty2qdLk9/34/show/light/ ).